# Warning: imresize is deprecated in Scipy 1.14.3

Tags: python, scipy, deprecation-warning

I get the following warning message:

```py
...\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:1: 
DeprecationWarning: `imresize` is deprecated!
`imresize` is deprecated in SciPy 1.0.0, and will be removed in 1.2.0.
Use ``skimage.transform.resize`` instead.
  """Entry point for launching an IPython kernel.
```

when I run

```py
image1 = imresize(image1, (new_size)).astype(np.int16)
image2 = imresize(image2, (new_size)).astype(np.int16)
```

I am unsure which version of Scipy I am using.

This is the code I am running:

```py
from skimage.transform import resize
import numpy as np
import imageio

image1 = imageio.imread("168_Left_Rio_Grande_Flooding_md.jpg")
image2 = imageio.imread("168_Right_Rio_Grande_Flooding_md.jpg")

new_size = np.asarray(image1.shape) / 5
new_size = new_size.astype(int) * 5

image1 = imresize(image1, (new_size)).astype(np.int16)
image2 = imresize(image2, (new_size)).astype(np.int16)
```

I would like to be able to compute the difference between image1 and image2. image1 is a land image and impage2 is a land image a couple of years later. The difference image would hence be such that the values of the pixels associated with land changes will have values significantly different from those of the pixels associated with unchanged areas.

```py
diff_image = abs(image1 - image2)
```

Comment: What is the question exactly? The warning message suggests you to move to [scikit-image](https://scikit-image.org) in the future, or you can use any other image processing package like [Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io). You can check your SciPy version with `scipy.version.full_version` or `scipy.__version__`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I use Jupyter notebook. ```python scipy.version.full_version``` does not work. I am new to python and jupyter notebook. How can I move to scikit-image? do you have any piece of code I can copy paste to have resize my image?

Comment: I mean you don't _need_ to change your code, unless you have to upgrade SciPy to a version where the function is removed. By the way, according to the current documentation of [`scipy.misc.imresize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-1.2.1/reference/generated/scipy.misc.imresize.html#scipy.misc.imresize) (v1.2.1), it seems the function removal has been delayed to v1.3.0, and the suggestion is now to use Pillow (although scikit-image should be just as good).

Comment: In any case, you can keep using what you have, or use [`skimage.transform.resize`](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.transform.html#resize), which you seem to have already installed? Here is an example: [Rescale, resize, and downscale](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/auto_examples/transform/plot_rescale.html).

Comment: Thank you again for your prompt reply. It does not work, I tried ```python image_resized = resize(image1, (image1.shape[0], image1.shape[1]),
                       anti_aliasing=True)``` and got the following error ```python TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-51610526c8f9> in <module>()
      2 
      3 image_resized = resize(image1, (image1.shape[0], image1.shape[1]),
----> 4                        anti_aliasing=True)

TypeError: resize() got an unexpected keyword argument 'anti_aliasing' ```

Comment: I tried also ```python image_resized = resize(image1, (image1.shape[0], image1.shape[1])) ``` and got the following error ```python UserWarning: The default mode, 'constant', will be changed to 'reflect' in skimage 0.15.
  warn("The default mode, 'constant', will be changed to 'reflect' in " ```

Comment: I do have  ```python skimage.transform.resize ``` installed

Comment: An `anti_aliasing` parameter was added to `resize` on scikit-image 0.14 (see [Release notes](https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/blob/master/doc/release/release_0.14.rst#improvements)). The second message is just a warning, to avoid it just pass the preferred `mode` (e.g. `mode='constant'` or `mode='reflect'`).

Answer (score 5):

If someone is still searching, then as per the official documentation of scipy.misc.imresize [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-1.2.1/reference/generated/scipy.misc.imresize.html), you can use the following to resize image:

> install Pillow package (pip install Pillow)

```
from PIL import Image       
resized_image = numpy.array(Image.fromarray(original_image).resize(newsize))
```